# Set negative cumulative sum to zero Can someone advise the best approach to do this?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with a amount column which has both negative and positive values.I want to calculate the sum of values and set negative cumulative sum to zero.

```
date        amount  actu_cusum  exp_cusum
22-06-2018  60.626   60.626      60.626
29-06-2018  -78.309 -17.683       0
02-07-2018  -0.824  -18.507       0
09-07-2018  -0.822  -19.329       0
10-07-2018  14.79   -4.539       14.79
29-07-2018  20      15.461       34.79
30-07-2018  -30     -24.539      4.79
31-07-2018  15      -9.539       19.79


update a set a.calamount= z.cusum
from #temp a, 
( select CustomerCode,  date ,amount, 
SUM(totaumamount) over ( partition by CustomerCode order by date )
as cusum from #temp
) z
where a.customercode = z.customercode and a.date = z.date
```

Comment: What "SQL" is this?  What is your DBMS?  "SQL" is just a query language used by many DBMSs.

Comment: Looks very much like SQL-Server. Your column `customercode` seems to be missing in the sample data section.

Comment: Could it be that the challenge is to calculate those expected  [exp_cusum] results? If that's so then this question is not as simple as that duplicate question that locked this post. And it should be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

(You are missing columns and tables in your question)
You can use:

```
... set a.calamount = case when z.cusum < 0 then 0 else z.cusum end ...
```

EDIT: For individual negative values:

```
update a set a.calamount= z.cusum
from #temp a, 
( select CustomerCode,  date ,amount, 
SUM(case when totaumamount < 0 then 0 else totaumamount end) over ( partition by CustomerCode order by date )
as cusum from #temp
) z
where a.customercode = z.customercode and a.date = z.date
```

Comment: I have apply this case but result is not matching because cusum contains the previous value result of that case is                                                                     
     new result apply case function                                                                    
                   60.626
                    0
                    0
                    0
                     -4.539       
                   15.461
                   -24.539
                   -9.539

Comment: @Ashwini, sorry I don't understand what you mean. Would you give some sample data WITH expected output. Are you trying to set the result to 0 or each individual value? I will edit my answer for individual values too.

Comment: date        amount     actu_cusum  exp_cusum
22-06-2018  60.626   60.626      60.626
29-06-2018  -78.309  -17.683       0
02-07-2018  -0.824   -18.507        0
31-07-2018   15         -3.507    19.79                                                                        I want to set  negative sum of actu_cusum column  to zero and it should pick zero for next record but at this case its pick the negative record so i am not getting the correct output